# Performing a ModelAdmin action in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-managers

I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
# from the docs
def make_published(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    queryset.update(status='p')
```

But I'm not using the Django admin site - I just need to be able to do this type of functionality elsewhere in my site.

Where should something like this be defined? In a model manager?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure why you want this.

An admin action is very specific, for use within the admin's changelist screen. There needs to be a special syntax, as you don't otherwise have control of that part of the application. If you want to perform an action on a queryset elsewhere on your site, you can just do it: you don't need any special way of doing so.

Comment: I think he just wants a DRY way of doing it.

Comment: @dan-klasson - yes exactly, Daniel - is there a DRY way of doing this?